# Magento2 How to refresh Admin Order Create Order Total Section

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, totals

I am creating new order from backend and i have to refresh order total section after my custom ajax request.

does any one know how i can achive this ?

[image]

Comment: You need to call the quote collect total method there same done on the shipping method selection or payment method selection.

Comment: Thank you @Dhiren Vasoya , i got the solution with reference of magento shipping method selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of below code i got my problem solution

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: url.build("/admin/router/controller/customfee"), 
            data: {option: 1},
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: 'json'
            }).done(
                 function (response) { 
                   window.order.loadArea(['custom_fee', 'totals'], true);
                 }   
               ).fail(
                    function (response) { 
                    }
                );
```

Comment: Can you help me how this loadArea work and send data to php function.

Comment: @SurajPrajapat Load area is not a data so we can not send it php but you can get "custom_fee" from quote in your js file and send to PHP via another Ajax Request

Comment: i am trying to change custom fee in total via ajax request but its not working.